# give temporary access to folder to copy file from application

Tags: python, ldap

Users have permission to a folder ( /central/development/plan ). When they run a script. 
It copies a file from their machine to folder. It is not desirable to give access at user level.

```
import maya.utils
.
.
newMayaFileName = folderLocation + "/" + fn + self.fileExtension
self.exportCommand = "cmds.file(\"%s\", exportSelected=True, type=\"mayaAscii\",force=True)" % newMayaFileName
expResult = maya.utils.executeInMainThreadWithResult( "%s" % self.exportCommand)

.
.
```

Permission should happen at script level. ( Is it possible ? )

Only an application should have access to copy file to a folder ( on central location, no temporary folder ).

No user should have write permission to this folder.

Is it possible to achieve this. ? . If yes, How. ?

If not, is it possible to create something like this. ?

Can python-ldap (on centos 6.4 ) help achieve this. ?. How ?

Did any body else have this need. How did you handle it. ?

Currently, i've tried ldap authentication. ( https://gist.github.com/ibeex/1288159 ). But i know there is something missing.

How does one know that a folder ( /central/development/plan ) now has access to export file from script ( as seen in code above )

Thx,

Nish

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot construct a script to give itself permission. This would be the same as giving a user the permissions at user level because they could just write a script to do what they want to do and give the script permissions.

What I would recommend is getting a service account or an admin account to run the script through a scheduler if it is a repeated task.

Comment: It is an user driven task. as a matter of fact, will ldap authentication in any way help in such a cause. It's a heresay.

Comment: I've looked through a few sites and can't find any way at all to grant permissions to the script itself rather than the user running it. I think permissions have to be granted at user level or permissions of the file itself have to be altered.